# Instance Method properties

Tags: python, function, oop, instance, init

What could be the correct option based on the instance method used in the Code

```
class People():

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def get_name(self):
    print(self.name)

person1 = People("John")
person2 = People("Mary")
person1.get_name()
```

Select one:

1. The `__init__` method is used to set initial values for attributes.
2. `person1` and `person2` are two different instances of the `People` class..
3. `person2` has a different value for 'name' than `person1`.
4. 'self' is not needed in `def get_name(self):`

I am new to functions and trying to learn from practicing problems, I didn't get the answer to this question.

Comment: Trick question -- it says "select one," but **three** of those answers are correct.  Write in "Nice try, prof!" and turn in for extra credit.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Anticipating a trick question, is the first sentence *your* question, or the *question's* question? I ask, because the phrasing could apply to the *most relevant answer* for only the one line containing `person1.get_name()`.

Comment: Or maybe the quiz actually asked which one is *not* true?

Comment: first 3 options are correct. The fourth one is incorrect. All methods in a class require `self` to make them a part of the class and this is automatically passed when the method is called. `self` basically refers to the object through which the method was called.